# Python: How do I use variables in a string pulled from a json file?

Tags: python, json, discord.py

So I have a string stored in a JSON file, but when I pull it into my Python code, there are certain parts I want to replace with variables. How would I go about doing that? Here's what I currently have that's relevant: (I'm coding as discord bot with discord.py if that changes anything)

```
guildname = member.guild.name
        memberid = member.id
        await thatchannel.send(f"{config['newmembermessage']}")
```

and from the json file

```
{
    "modlogsid": 492165353544351745,
    "enablenewmemberchannel": false,
    "newmemberchannel": "465976927932",
    "newmembermessage": "Welcome to {guildname}, <@{memberid}>! Read <#477198353541627913> and you're set, enjoy!"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Treat `config["newmembermessage"]` as you would any other string.

`new_member_message = config["newmembermessage"].format(guildname, memberid)`

Comment: In the JSON file, would I change the {guildname} and {memberid} to just {} or keep it like that?

Comment: I do have to switch them, just tested that. Thanks for the help.